# Show Mac OS X sliding dialog with wxPython

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, wxpython

Is it possible to create the Mac OS X style sliding in wxPython?
Such as this:
[image: Mac OS X sliding dialog]

Is it possible to have this kind of dialog resize or can it only be simple message dialogs?

I think this kind of dialog box is called a sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this bug](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/9459), it looks like dialogs-as-sheets still has not been implemented in wxWidgets. Various patches were proposed, but apparently none were accepted.

Comment: Has no one managed to implement it using ctypes similar to this http://wiki.wxpython.org/NativeMacOSXToolbarSelection